# Android Download Manager, COLUMN_STATUS is 7. What does this means?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download a `zip` file which is nearly 200MB in size. In order for me to get the current downloaded bytes I use following code snippet.

```
while ((cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING) ||(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING)) {
    downloadedLength = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
}
```

Every time `(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)` returns me `int` 7.

What I want to achieve through this is to get the download progress until it reaches the status `SUCCESS`

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to show progress inside your app.

Once you have the cursor object, you can basically do this to show progress.

```
Cursor c = dm.query(query);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int totalSizeIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES);
    int downloadedIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR);
    long totalSize = c.getInt(totalSizeIndex);
    long downloaded = c.getInt(downloadedIndex);
    double progress = 0.0;
    if (size != -1) {
        progress = downloaded * 100.0 / totalSize;
    }
}
```

downloaded * 100.0 / totalSize calculates the percentage.

Comment: c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR does this run recurrently until the download is successful? I need to monitor the download from 0 - 100%. That's why I put c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR) inside a while loop. Every time, if the status is PENDING or RUNNING until SUCCESS I want to get the downloaded byte so far

Comment: Yes, c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES) will run all the time. But the value you get will always be the same. Say you're downloading a 4 Mb file, in every iteration of the loop you will be getting 4 Mb. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, that's true COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES will return the full download size. But what I need to know is how does COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR will provide values. Do we need to call this inside a loop? to get the downloaded byte values so far

Comment: Yes, that gives you the download progress. Let's say after 1st loop iteration, DownloadManager has downloaded 1Mb of total 4 Mb which is 25%, then in the next iteration, it's 2MB which is 50%. So it should be called in a loop to get how much the download has progressed.

Comment: That's true. In order to loop to continue I check the cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)'s output. The loop should continue while the COLUMN_STATUS is either STATUS_PENDING or STATUS_RUNNING.

But the problem is cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS) returns Int 7. Why is this?

Comment: cursor.getColumnIndex() method returns the index which is 7. Now when you use this index in let's say cursor.getIndex(7) you'll get some other value which may/may not be needed in your app.

Answer (score 0):

7 is the index aka column number for the STATUS value.

You need to call `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))` to get the actual value of the column